# Descomposicion de JSON array en sus componentes

Tags: java, json

Hola a todos me dirijo a vds a ver si me pudieran echar una mano.
Tengo un fichero JSON (datos.json) con la estructura :

```
[
  {
    "cli_nombre": "Miguel",
    "cli_tel1": "",
    "cli_tel2": "723223319805",
    "cli_apellidos": "lopez",
    "prov_id": "1",
    "descripcion": "antonia_NAVARRO_72231_0_0_1_1_1",
    "ssid": "",
    "clavewifi": ""
  },
  {
    "cli_nombre": "Francisca",
    "cli_tel1": "952236146458",
    "cli_tel2": "663338821642",
    "cli_apellidos": "gomez",
    "prov_id": "2",
    "descripcion": "joseA_NAVARRO_LE_0_0_1_1_1",
    "ssid": "",
    "clavewifi": ""
  },
....
]
```

y quiero poder tener uno a uno los campos para poder tratarlos ... trabajo en Java y he probado con varias formas pero no logro conseguirlo ....
La idea es conseguir una a una las claves y los valores que existen en el fichero para usarlos luego en otras aplicaciones...

He llegado a Ver que es un Array. 
necesito tener uno a uno los campos "cli_nombre", "cli_tel1", .. etc para saber cuantos campos claves tengo en cada uno de los campos entre {},
 La razon de eso es que cuandomvuelva a recibir otro fichero el numero de los campos y su valor asi como su cantidad va a ser distintas,,,

Es decir .. necesito saber la estructura de cada registro para luego enviarlo a un JASPERREPORT para generar un listado ...

```js
    String cadena;
      FileReader f = new FileReader("c:/tools/datos.Json"); 
      BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);  
      while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {       
             System.out.println(cadena);
           String studentName9 = scanner0.nextLine();  
        }
        b.close();
```

con esto he lleago a tener independiente cada uno de los registros , pero no se como saber que esos registros se componen de ....

```js
 {
    "cli_nombre": "Miguel",
    "cli_tel1": "",
    "cli_tel2": "723223319805",
    "cli_apellidos": "lopez",
    "prov_id": "1",
    "descripcion": "antonia_NAVARRO_72231_0_0_1_1_1",
    "ssid": "",
    "clavewifi": ""
  },
  
  cli_nombre
  cli_tel1
  cli_tel2
  .......
```

Gracias  a todos

Comment: Supongo que as intentado de algo? pon el codigo, los errores para que te puedan ayudar

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:/tools/datos.json");
        JsonElement datos = parser.parse(fr);
        System.out.println(fr);
        String studentName = scanner.nextLine();
        DataBeanList(datos);

Comment: private static  void BuscaEstruc(JsonObject datos01) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" ESTRUCTURA  ");
        JsonArray valor99 = new JsonArray(datos01);
         for (int i = 0; i < valor99.length(); i++) {
           JsonObject object = valor99.getJsonObject(i);
            clave = object.getString(i); 
           }

Comment: son las dos partes del programa en la primera , preparo los datos como son el nombre del fichero y demas.. en lasegunda parte es como intento leerlo .... soy nuevo en esto pero elm caso es que por un nlado me dice que es un objeto JSON y por otro que es un Array .. y me esta volviendo loco ..

Comment: trabajo con NETBEANS, soy nuevo en este tipo de programacion y no se donde puedo ver algo "serio" de estos tipos de ficheros JSON - ARRAY   y JSON_OBJECT .. q lio !!!

Comment: los errores son multiples pues me da que al intentar leer el fichero rechaza mis comando porque es un fichero ... que ya no se si es  ARRAY o OBJECT!!!!

Comment: de todas formas gracias por tomarte interes

Comment: En vez de ponerlos en el comentario ponlo en la pregunta. Quedará más claro

Comment: @rafacarm nos puedes dejar ver que tienes implementados o como lo has tratado de solucionar.

Comment: ya lo he ampliado con mas ejemplos a ver si me podeis ayudar ... gracias de nuevo ..

Comment: Lo más sencillo es crearte un objeto de tipo JsonArray e ir recorriendo sus valores, más aún cuando sabes los nombres de los campos que te va a devolver.

Comment: ya he analizado el tipo de datos del fichero con isJsonArray(), y me dice que si q es  un fichero array, pero no se como tocarlo para desbrozar el fichero pues siempre se queja que el  tipo no es array ... perdona por no saber mas ...

Comment: y el tema es que nunca voy a saber los nombres de los campos hasta que tenga el fichero y la aplicacion que tengo que hacer es que leamese fichero , vea que campos tiene, cuantos y luego monte un informe a partir de ese fichero .....

Answer (score 0):

Para parsear un json te recomiendo que primero hacer la modelizacion del objeto. Viendo el json podemos deducir que es algun tipo de lista de clientes, entonces crearemos la clase cliente con todos los campos que tiene el json.

```
public class Cliente {
  String nombre;
  String tel1;
  String tel2;
  //... y asi seguimos con todos los campos que tenga el json
}
```

Y posteriormente armamos un metodo que lea el archivo y nos devuelva un el Array de Clientes

```
private Array<Cliente> parseClients(String fileName){
   Array<Cliente> clientes = new Array()

   //No tengas miedo de leer todo el archivo y meterlo en un string, hoy en dia tenemos gb de ram y un archivo json no deberia pesar casi nada.
   String fileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));

   //Ahora instanciamos un objeto json con el String que ya conseguiste(sera JSONObject o JSONArray segun el caso)
   JSONArray json = new JSONArray(fileContent);

   //Recorro el array para parsear cada cliente
   for (JSONObject jclient : json){ 
   //Instancia tu modelo de Cliente para que contenga los datos que vayas a necesitar
      Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

      //Asi consigo finalmente los campos del json
      cliente.nombre = jclient.getString("nombre");
      cliente.tel1 = jclient.getString("tel1");
      cliente.tel2 = jclient.getDouble("tel2");
      //Continuar con los demas campos...
      clientes.add(cliente)
   }
   return clientes;
}
```

Seguramente me estan faltando varios try catch dentro del codigo, pero confio en que los pondras donde mas te convengan.

Tené en cuenta que formas de parsear json en java hay miles, esta que te pasé es de las mas claras a mi parecer. Pero tambien te recomiendo que mires la libreria de [json-simple](https://howtodoinjava.com/library/json-simple-read-write-json-examples/)

Comment: Lei ademas en los comentarios que no sabes los nombres de los campos que tendra el json. Eso es raro pero no te preocupes hay dos metodos dentro del json que te van a ayudar mucho. json.keys() que te devolvera un iterador que podes usar para conseguir las keys y con eso parsear el json. Tambien existe el json.has("una_key_que_podria_no_estar") que te ayudara para verificar que el campo exista antes de intentar leerlo.

Comment: el asunto es que esta aplicacion es para una empresa para la que estoy de practicas y me han puesto este problema ... el JSON que me envian nunca sabre las columnas .. entonces la aplicacion  tiene que leer el fichero, descubrir cuantas columnas y que datos trae y generar un listado con JasperReport ..

Comment: con lo que el ejemplo que pones en realidad no me sirve.. nunca voy a poder crear la clase cliente pues no se si es cliente o servicios o articulos .... lo de la key si me sirve , pues si puedo descomponer los campos del array por cada key tengo su campo , y al contar las keys dentro de cada array ya tengo las columnas del listado y su descripcion ... y si .. es lioso ,... pero me juego en ello muchas cosas...

Comment: Vengo de COBOL en UNIX, y he echo cosas en Visual , pero Java poca idea ...gracias por tu ayuda... poco a poco me voy enterando ..

Comment: No uso jasperReport, asi que no se como armaras el reporte, pero seguramente haciendo un bucle para iterar sobre el array que te da json.keys() vas a poder conseguir todos los valores y armar el reporte que buscas. Si necesitas mas ayuda solo avisa. Exitos colega.

Comment: de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda ,, voy a intentar lo q dices pues lo deljasperreport es una segunda parte .. voy a ello !!!

Comment: ya encontre la solucion solo me falta sacar el orden .. necesito solo los campos del primer registro .. la explicacion la pongo en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo consegui .....

```js
  JsonParser fichero = new JsonParser();
    Object objeto =  fichero.parse(new FileReader("c:/tools/datos.Json"));
    JsonArray detalle = (JsonArray) objeto;
    Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = detalle.iterator();

  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) iterator.next();

            jsonObject.keySet().forEach((key) -> {
                System.out.println(key + ":" + jsonObject.get(key));
                   });
}
```

con esto ya logre descomponer uno a uno los campos de los que se compone el fichero, solo me queda una cosa .. el orden cuando los campos se repiten necesito sabes solo los campos del primer array, con eso tendre los campos del registro.

```js
{
    "cli_nombre": "Miguel",
    "cli_tel1": "",
    "cli_tel2": "723223319805",
    "cli_apellidos": "lopez",
    "prov_id": "1",
    "descripcion": "antonia_NAVARRO_72231_0_0_1_1_1",
    "ssid": "",
    "clavewifi": ""
  }
  del primer registro  los campos son 
  no. orden -----  campo
  1         -----  cli_nombre
  2         -----  cli-tel
  .....
  8         -----  clavewifi
```

Los problemas que he tenido han sido en gran parte las librerias que estaba utilizando.
Con lo que  necesito es saber el orden de los campos dentro del primer registro registro.
Supongo que habra algun comando JSONOBJECT que presente la informacion del orden que tiene en el fichero ...
Si me podeis ayudar os lo seguire agradeciendo .....

Answer (score 0):

A mi ultima pregunta de como leer esos campos y quedarme con los datos del primer registro... eso lo quiero para ver como puedo utilizar esa informacion del tipo de columnas y cantidad para generan un  fichero en JASONREPORT, lo ultimo que me falta lo encontre con :

```js
private static  void Buscacolumnas() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
    System.out.println(" columnas  listado"); 
       int contador = 0 ;        
       String cadena;
        FileReader f = new FileReader("c:/tools/estructura.Json");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
            contador = contador + 1;
            System.out.println(cadena);
            
        }
        b.close();
   

        System.out.println("contador columnas : " + contador);
        Scanner scanner0 = new Scanner(System.in); 
 } 
}
```

Con esto obtengo el total de columnas y lo q tiene cada una de ellas.... estas columnas iran cambiando ,pues el fichero que leera esta apolicacion cambiara tanto de numero de columnas como las columnas en si n.. una vez pueden ser de articulo s y otras de clientes .....
Con lo que mi siguiente paso es ver como en JASONREPORT , puedo generar alguna modificacion en el fichero *.JXRML , para que cada vez que le llegue la informacion de las columnas me cree la parte de las columnas que necesito...
Os vuelvo a pedir ayuda por si sabeis algo de esto ......... Un Saludo!!!